# C++: Function call error: identifier "name" is undefined, when already defined?

Tags: c++, class

I'm having problems with several C++ programs simply not wanting to run the functions that are defined clearly in a public class above main. I've looked far and wide for answers, but similar problems are the result of not having a scope resolution operator or something similar. As far as I can tell, everything required to call this function is there.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h> 
using namespace std;

class Box{
public:
    Box();
    Box(int x, int y);
    Box(int x, int y, char type);
    Box(char type);
    //Accessor functions:
    int GetY();
    int GetX();
    char GetChar();
    //Mutator functions:
    void SetCoords(int x, int y);
    void SetChar(char x);
    //Output function:
    void printbox(void);

private:
    int ycoord;
    int xcoord;
    char drawing;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Box();
    printbox();
    return 0;
};

void Box::printbox(void){
    //working code
};
```

What I get instead is error C3861: 'printbox' identifier not found. What's missing that lets the printbox (and other functions like these) run?

Comment: I think you just need to call printbox() on an **instance** variable of the Box class.  For example `mybox = Box();` then `mybox.printbox();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printbox` is a method therefore you have to call it on an object of type `Box`. Like this

```
Box b;
b.printbox();
```

Comment: Works, thank you! I forgot all about the dot operator for some reason. Hopefully someone else with the same problem will find this helpful!